# Scan for first image in post and display it

Tags: post-thumbnails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve 1st image in post and set it as featured image, when post is saved/updated](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45529/retrieve-1st-image-in-post-and-set-it-as-featured-image-when-post-is-saved-upda)
>   [VT-resize image and display it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50381/vt-resize-image-and-display-it)

ok guys, I have this script which I modified in order to crop the image before being displayed.

```
// Get URL of first image in a post
function catch_that_image() {
global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

// no image found display default image instead
if(empty($first_img)){
$first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
}

 $first_img = vt_resize( $first_img, '', 608, 250, true );


return $first_img;
}
```

this is the code I use to display it:

```
<img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="608" height="250" />
```

The vt_resize function is already built in within the theme. However the code is not returning the url, it just return an array. What am I doing wrong?

I hope a nice person answers to my question, thank you =)

Comment: [FAQ > Etiquette](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette). Your first and last warning.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to not help with your existing code but if you are open to using a plugin I can recommend: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/

It is great as it grabs the first image, or a featured image if you have one. You can also specify the dimensions to crop the image and an optional fallback image in case there is no image in the post.

You can just use `<?php get_the_image(); ?>` in a template and it will default to:

```
$defaults = array(
    'meta_key' => array( 'Thumbnail', 'thumbnail' ),
    'post_id' => $post->ID,
    'attachment' => true,
    'the_post_thumbnail' => true,
    'size' => 'thumbnail',
    'default_image' => false,
    'order_of_image' => 1,
    'link_to_post' => true,
    'image_class' => false,
    'image_scan' => false,
    'width' => false,
    'height' => false,
    'format' => 'img',
    'meta_key_save' => false,
    'callback' => null,
    'cache' => true,
    'echo' => true
);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. One more question... Will this consume too much server resources? Because I have thousands of visits daily. I cannot use timthumb for that matter because it is resource intensive. Is this plugin better?

Comment: From experience, yes much better! I too gave up on using timthumb. But I'm not techie enough to talk specifics. Maybe take a look at: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/faq/

Comment: Caroline for some reason the plugin does not crop the images :(

Comment: Have you tried selecting 'Crop thumbnail to exact dimensions (normally thumbnails are proportional)' under Media Settings?

Comment: I am not using thumbnails, I am extracting the first image of a post so there are many different sizes. I have tried many plugins and no luck!

Comment: Yes, but this plugin will grab the image at the full size then resize and display it at thumbnail size (by default). You can also choose to display medium, large, full or any custom size.

Comment: I see, it is resizing the image but it's not keeping the its ratio aspect, thus, the image looks distorted

Comment: I think you might have to use the thumbnail size for it to be cropped not distorted. See my example here: http://www.carolineelisa.com/shellsnow/blog/beauty/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin from the Wordpress Plugin Directory seems to do what you need - [Auto post thumbnail](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/)

Comment: hi travis, thank you but I already tried it out and it was giving me a bunch of errors so I had to deactivate it.